# AddSingleton() with a zero argument constructor

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

Please see the code below:

```
services.AddMvc();

services.AddSingleton();

services.Configure(o =>
        o.ClientModelValidatorProviders.Add(new YouTubeModelValidatorProvider()));
```

It was taken from a Microsoft blog here: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/mvpawardprogram/2017/01/03/asp-net-core-mvc/.  I get a compilation error because there is no method called AddSingleton, which accepts no arguments.  Is this just a typo or am I missing something important here? The code seems to work properly without the line of code.

I am wandering if any of the classes below: "An alternative implementation based on type metadata" should be a singleton?

Comment: There was never such an parameterless/typeless overload of `AddSingleton` to `IServiceCollection`, its a mistake in the blog post. A parameterless/typeless method call would make no sense as this method is used to register new types (or instances or factories) to .NET Core's DI/IoC container abstractions.

Comment: @Tseng, thanks.  Do you think any of the classes under the title:  "An alternative implementation based on type metadata"  should be a singleton? Perhaps the author forgot to add the two arguments?

Comment: Obviously from the comments, the code examples weren't marked as code in the initial post and MSDN posts (and comments) are know to remove angle brackets (`<`, `>`) and the content in between them, so the type information probably got lost when it was put back into code blocks. It's probably meant to be `services.AddSingleton<IValidationAttributeAdapterProvider, CustomValidatiomAttributeAdapterProvider>();` from the earlier code example

Comment: I don't see any type in that section thats injected, they are all `new`d

Comment: @Tseng, I don't understand your last comment.  I know what dependency injection is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I get a compilation error because there is no method called AddSingleton, which accepts no arguments. Is this just a typo or am I missing something important here?

For this line `services.AddSingleton();`, I think it's a mistake that forgetting to remove or it should be `services.AddSingleton<IValidationAttributeAdapterProvider,CustomValidatiomAttributeAdapterProvider>();`.

As the `Conclusion` from the blog

> In summary, client validation rules require the implementation of the IClientModelValidator interface. If the client rule comes from a validation attribute we may inherit from AttributeAdapterBase, otherwise we have to implement it from the scratch. Client rules based on validation attributes are installed by substituting the default IValidationAttributeAdapterProvider and configuring the custom implementation in the ConfigureServices section of our application. If not, we need to implement the basic IClientModelValidatorProvider interface, and add it to the ClientModelValidatorProviders list contained in the MVcViewOptions. On the JavaScript side, we must provide a function that implements the actual validation logic and an adapter that takes care of attaching properly this validation logic to the input field, when it is invoked by the unobtrusive attributes parser.

For `services.AddSingleton<IValidationAttributeAdapterProvider,CustomValidatiomAttributeAdapterProvider>();`, it is correspoinding to `configuring the custom implementation in the ConfigureServices section of our application`.

For `services.Configure(o => o.ClientModelValidatorProviders.Add(new YouTubeModelValidatorProvider()));`, it is correspoinding to `add it to the ClientModelValidatorProviders list contained in the MVcViewOptions`.